# Azerbaijani citizen with US Green Card, transiting in European airports. Do I need to obtain a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, transit-visas

I will move to the USA from Azerbaijan (I am an Azerbaijani citizen with a Green Card). I am planning to buy tickets with 3 stops: Sofia (Bulgaria), Athens (Greece) and Barcelona (Spain). The transits are within these airports: I will not leave them. Do I need to obtain a Transit Schengen visa?

Here are the details:

- [May 22 08:30] Baku GYD - 10:55 Sofia SOF | Azerbaijan Airlines 3h 25m
- Layover in Sofia for 3h.
- 13:55 Sofia SOF - 15:10 Athens | ATH Aegean 1h 15m
- Layover in Athens for 17h 35m.
- [Wed 23 May 08:45] Athens ATH 11:00 Barcelona BCN | Aegean 3h 15m
- Layover in Barcelona for 5h.
- 16:00 Barcelona BCN - 18:15 Boston BOS

Answer (score 6):

**You cannot do this trip on a transit visa. You will need to obtain a Schengen entry visa.**

This is because Athens and Barcelona are both in the Schengen area. Therefore the flight between them counts as an internal flight. You will need to clear immigration in Athens in order to board the flight to Barcelona.

More information can be found in the answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area).

Comment: More importantly, they need to pass through passport control at the Schengen external border in Athens.